# Problems with invisible planes

Tags: three.js

I use three.js obj and mtl loader. There are no problems with the examples, but when i try to use my own .obj file, somes planes don't appear. It's always the sames planes.

I've taken a look at my .obj and .mtl files, but it's ok. My script works with the example models. I've import / export my .obj files from blender, but there are always problems of invisible planes. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that faces which have more than 4 vertices do not appear after loading from the .obj file. In blender you can triangulate the faces in question by selecting them and hitting "Ctrl + T"

Another common problem is that some of the normals are flipped. Try to recalculate them in blender using: "Recalculate normals outside".Select all your faces and do "Ctrl + N"

Comment: that don't resolve my problem ='( and it's the sames planes which are invisible

Comment: Try to triangulate the faces. I just added the suggestion to the answer above, after facing the same problem yesterday ;)